# Extract object from PointCloud segment_table

Tags: python, image-segmentation, point-clouds, open3d

I'm using Open3d to segment the objects on a table with segment_plane method.
I need to extract data from each of the segmented objects (center, rotation) or, even better, to have on each object a bounding box (and also center end extension).
Is there a way?
This is my (simple) code and an image of the segmented table

```
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pc2
import pytransform3d.rotations as pyrot
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R


def get_point_cloud_from_ros(debug=False, radius=0.25):
    point_cloud = rospy.wait_for_message("/camera/depth/color/points", PointCloud2)
    rospy.loginfo("Point got from /camera/depth/color/points")
    pc = []
    for p in pc2.read_points(point_cloud, field_names=("x", "y", "z"), skip_nans=True):
        if np.linalg.norm(p) > radius:
            pc.append([p[0], p[1], p[2]])
    
    # Segmentation of Point Cloud
    xyz = np.asarray(pc)
    idx = np.where(xyz[:, 2] > 0.55)     # Prune point cloud to 0.8 meters from camera in z direction
    xyz = xyz[idx]

    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
    print ('Received point cloud')

    if debug:
        o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])

    return pcd

def segment_table(pcd):
    plane_model, inliers = pcd.segment_plane(distance_threshold=0.005, ransac_n=5, num_iterations=100)
    [a, b, c, d] = plane_model

    # Partial Point Cloud
    inlier_cloud = pcd.select_by_index(inliers)
    outlier_cloud = pcd.select_by_index(inliers, invert=True)

    return inlier_cloud, outlier_cloud



if __name__ == '__main__':

    rospy.init_node('pcl_vis', anonymous=True)
    point_cloud = rospy.wait_for_message("/camera/depth/color/points", PointCloud2)

    print("starting pointcloud segmentation")
    debug = True
    pcd = get_point_cloud_from_ros(debug)

    mesh_coord_frame = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(size=0.3, origin=[0, 0, 0.45])

    print ('Table Segmentation')
    table_cloud, object_cloud = segment_table(pcd)

    object_cloud.paint_uniform_color([1, 0, 0])
    table_cloud.paint_uniform_color([0, 0, 1])

    
    if debug:
        o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([table_cloud, object_cloud])
```

[image: Segmented table] [image: Gazebo table]